# Using libcurl on visual c++ to login to a website，How to check login success?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I use the demo to login a website "http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login/".
and the return value from console is many html information. just like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Hack This Site! :: Login</title>
<meta name="verify-v1" content="s/YXn7eQrMBoF9PL5jLJDiWpAxEXpJzE9JLg/zM4C2Y=" />
Freenode for general discussion or any questions you h...</div>
............
<br />
<br />
<span style="font-size: 10px;"><a href="/news/view/690">read more...</a> | <a 
</body> 
</html>
```

But I don't know Is it on behalf of login success?
MY demo code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>


int main()
{

curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
CURL * myHandle = curl_easy_init ( );

// Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");

// Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login/");
curl_easy_perform( myHandle );


// Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login/");
// Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
char *data="username=your_username_here&password=your_password_here";
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_perform( myHandle );

curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );


return 0;
}
```

Please help me , thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood there is two ways. 
A bit easier is to get return value from your last *curl_easy_perform* function:

```
 CURLcode res;
 res = curl_easy_perform(myHandle);
```

Then you have to decide what to do with result - whether to compare with [CURLE_OK](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) or result you need.

A bit longer way is to use *[curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)* function with your *myHandle* variable before you cleanup it. There you can find CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE in the struct filled by function.

Comment: If that completely not what you wanted — just let me know, I'll delete that

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's satified my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to get the source code back. Then, juste analyse it to know if this is the source code of a succesfull conection or not.
Here is an example to recover the source code : [getinmemory.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!